# Error on setOnItemClickListener in gridView

Tags: android, gridview

I programming an galery app with only images of app, not read the phone images
but i getting an error on use `gridView.setOnItemClickListener`.

This is de code:

```
    try {
        fotos = new ParserFotos(this).getFotos();

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.layout_grid_view, fotos);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            ImageItem item = (ImageItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Fotos.this, FotosDeatils.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", item.getTitle());
            intent.putExtra("image", item.getImage());

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

But he say the error: http://pastebin.com/raw/TGLeJ3Uh

Heres my grid view class: http://pastebin.com/raw/49MzQtnW

Help me fast pleaze

Comment: It looks like `new ParserFotos(this).getFotos();` might be raising an exception - if so, it should be printed in your logcat above the NPE you've already posted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting your click listener on a grid view that is empty.

You don't need to set the ViewHolder to null. Instead before the if statement just declare it:

```
ViewHolder holder;
```

Also your array of images might be empty.

Comment: declare in wat class? of adapter or activty?

Comment: in your grid view class, within the getView() method.

Comment: Not worket, error in this line:
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

Comment: then try to instantiate it .

Comment: ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();  also as I said, you may not be getting anything stored to your array of photos

Comment: Help me to parse photos plz can sendme a code to parse this xml: http://pastebin.com/raw/BD1aTeqr